# How to run Hyperv Socket in Linux Guest VM

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, hypervisor

I am able to connect the HyperV Socket having Client - Windows & Server - Windows VM

```
Guid serviceId = Guid.Empty;
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Virtualization\GuestCommunicationServices\"))
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        foreach (var subKeyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using var subKey = key.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);

             if (subKey == null) continue;
             if (subKey.GetValue("ElementName").ToString() == "HV Socket")
             {
                 serviceId = new Guid(subKeyName);
             }
         }
     }
 }
 endpoint = new HyperVSocketEndPoint(HyperVSocketEndPoint.AF_HYPERV, Guid.Empty, serviceId);
 listenSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, (System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType)1);
```

I am not able to connect having the Client - Windows & Server - Linux VM I tried like this as per the [MSDN document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/make-integration-service).

```
Guid serviceId = new Guid("00000000-ca1d-4946-9e11-3b2ab3ab43c6");
endpoint = new HyperVSocketEndPoint(HyperVSocketEndPoint.AF_HYPERV, Guid.Empty, serviceId);
listenSocket = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(endpoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, (System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType)0);
```

For connecting to Linux guest (Server) : 00000000-ca1d-4946-9e11-3b2ab3ab43c6
to connect Windows host (client) : guid
How do I need to create the CID & port for Client & Server?